# Protected Downloads

Tags: html, css

I have coded a Website with a Page where the User can Download some Stuff. Now my Question is: How can I make it, that the User must to Enter a correct Password before Downloading.
Like this: BUTTON > PASSWORD TRUE > DOWNLOAD.

Sorry for my Bad English, i am from Germany.

Comment: Add Your Code For This Query

Comment: There are endless tutorials about both, http server based user authentication and also scripting based user handling. Please read some of those, follow them. I suggest you start with the http server based approach since apparently you are using static html files.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You could insist that the URL is only accessible via a POST containing the valid credentials.

Alternatively, knowing nothing about your stack, I would suggest verifying the credentials, setting a cookie, then sending a redirect to the download url and checking the cookie.